# Python package distribution with entry_point console_script

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools, python-packaging

I am preparing to deploy a Python package with the following layout:

```
MyPackage/
  setup.py
  MyPackage/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    lib/
      __init__.py
      utils.py
    db/
      __init__.py
      db1.py
      db2.py 
    tasks/
      __init__.py
      something.py
```

The `setup.py` contains:

```
setup(name = MyPackage,
      ...
      packages = find_packages(),
      include_package_data = True,
      entry_points = {"console_scripts" : [
          "do_something = MyPackage.__main__:main"
      ]})
```

`__main__.py` contains:

```
import tasks.something as something

something.my_function()
```

`something` module contains:

```
import db.db1 as db1
import db.db2 as db2

def my_function():
  db1.this_func(...)
  db2.that_func(...)
```

`db1` contains:

```
import sqlalchemy
import lib.utils as utils

def this_func(...):
  sqlalchemy.create_engine(...)
```

and `db2` contains:

```
import sqlalchemy
import lib.utils as utils

def that_func(...):
  sqlalchemy.create_engine(...)
```

When run by executing from the installed `site-packages` directory, `__main__.py` completes without issue. If I perform `import MyPackage.tasks.something as something` in an interactive session, the module also imports with issue. When I run the `console_scripts` script `do_something`, however, I receive `ModuleNotFound` errors for `tasks`.

What is causing my console script to fail to locate the subpackages?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably wrong imports; please add the contents of the `__main__.py` to the question.

Comment: What are exactly the commands that you call, and what are the full error messages that are generated? What are the commands you used to package the project and to install it? You mention a _console script entry point_ `do_something = MyPackage.__main__:main`, but there doesn't appear to be any `main` callable (function) in the `MyPackage/__main__.py` file.

Answer (score 5):

Change your imports, following this example:

*__main__.py*:

```py
import tasks.something as something

# to:

import MyPackage.tasks.something as something

# or

from .tasks import something as something
```

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here.

1. Import statements in `__main__.py` were implicit relative. Change them to absolute imports.
2. A `console_scripts` entry point target needs to resolve to a *callable which accepts no arguments*. In your case, that means the module `MyPackage/__main__.py` should define a callable `main`.

Change `__main__.py` like this:

```
from MyPackage.tasks import something

def main():
    # command line arguments parsing and logging configuration goes here ..
    something.my_function()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Similarly, you should change the import statements in `db1`, `db2`, and `something` into correct relative imports:

```
from ..db import db1
from ..db import db2
from ..lib import utils
```

Alternatively, use absolute imports:

```
from MyPackage.db import db1
from MyPackage.db import db2
from MyPackage.lib import utils
```