# How to package a Python project to be run in the console

Tags: python, packaging, python-packaging

I wrote a project in Python which uses multiple scripts (modules). The main script calls on the other modules and reads some files from a folder in order to perform its function.

I am trying to package it for distribution. I wish to make it a runable program from the command line, meaning, once the user downloads it and installs it, they can call the program like this:

```
$ python my_program -i arg1 -o arg2
```

or similar.

The tutorials I find online wrap the project in the form of a package that you can import.

```
>> import my_program
>> my_program.run_stuff(arg1, arg2)
```

That's not what I want.

Comment: What you probably mean is that you want to call it as `my_program -i arg1 -o arg2`.  They shouldn't need their own Python.  Tools like `pyinstaller` and `py2exe` can do that.  Alternatively, you can package it as a module, and people with Python can type `python -m my_program -i arg1 -o arg2`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you wrote "or similar", let's say you want to call the program like so:

```
$ my_program -i arg1 -o arg2
```

This is even shorter. It's also how we call ubiquitous Python tools like `pip`. And there is an established procedure to define an "entry point" (as it's known) for any Python package.

All Python packaging tools allow that. We could [use the classic Setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62050378) if we wanted to — that's [what Pip does](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/902b9e7a1a978816c34ab2329df4fcfec117ea78/setup.py#L76-L82). Or [use Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/pyproject/#scripts), a more modern alternative. But it's often easiest to set up with [Flit](https://flit.readthedocs.io).

In the simplest case, your package `my_program` only contains an `__init__.py` file that defines a function:

```py
def main():
    print('Running my program...')
```

That function would typically act on the command-line arguments in `sys.argv`. The function doesn't have to be called `main`, it could be any name, and it could also be in any other module of the package.

We can then define the entry point for the console script in the project's meta data. Flit reads that from a configuration file named `pyproject.toml` in the root folder. So the repository now looks like this:

```
.
├── my_program
│   └── __init__.py
└── pyproject.toml
```

Using the most recent standard for the meta data, [PEP 621](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0621), `pyproject.toml` would contain:

```
[project]
name = 'my_program'
version = '1.0.0'
description = 'Can be run in the console from anywhere.'

[project.scripts]
my_program = 'my_program:main'

[build-system]
requires = ['flit_core>=3.2,<4']
build-backend = 'flit_core.buildapi'
```

In the [[`project.scripts`] section](https://flit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyproject_toml.html#scripts-section) we have mapped the console command `my_program` to the `main` function in the top-level name space of the `my_program` package. Again, it could be any other function elsewhere in the package too.

Now we package the project:

```
$ flit build --format wheel
Copying package file(s) from my_program              I-flit_core.wheel
Writing metadata files                               I-flit_core.wheel
Writing the record of files                          I-flit_core.wheel
Built wheel: dist\my_program-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl  I-flit_core.wheel
```

This puts the packaged "wheel" in a folder named `dist`. We could upload that `.whl` file to [PyPI](https://pypi.org) for distribution, or install it with Pip right away:

```
$ pip install dist/my_program-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Processing .\dist\my_program-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: my-program
Successfully installed my-program-1.0.0
```

Now we can run the program like any other console application:

```
$ my_program
Running my program...
```

What Pip did there for us is, it created a small launcher for our package right next to its very own launcher. Just like it did [for Flit](https://github.com/takluyver/flit/blob/96751efce651f8bae8ccb9e7f144dac460b3f013/pyproject.toml#L43-L44) too. On Windows, for example, there is now a `my_program.exe` inside Python's `Scripts` folder, right next to `pip.exe` and `flit.exe`.